# How to properly set relationships in Core Data when using setValue and data already exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Let's say I have two objects: **Articles** and **Categories** with a many-many relationship between the two. For the sake of this example all relevant categories have already been added to the data store. When looping through data that holds edits for articles, there is category relationship information that needs to be saved.

I was planning on using the `-setValue` method in the `Article` class in order to set the relationships like so:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    if([key isEqualToString:@"categories"]){
        NSLog(@"trying to set categories...");
    }
}
```

The problem is that `value` isn't a `Category`, it is just a string (or array of strings) holding the title of a category. I could certainly do a lookup within this method for each category and assign it, but that seems inefficient when processing a whole bunch of articles at once. Another option is to populate an array of all possible categories and just filter, but my question is where to store that array? Should it be a class method on `Article`? Is there a way to pass in additional data to the `-setValue` method? Is there another, better  option for setting the relationship I'm not thinking of?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you implementing setValue:forKey:?  You should have a relationship between these two objects that is set up as many to many and work with the relationship directly.  It appears here that that you are doing this the hard way.

What is your end goal with this code?

### Update

If I understand you correctly, you have a blob of JSON data and you want to turn that into an object graph and it matches that object graph correct?  If so, please look at the code I wrote in this other answer:

[JSON and Core Data on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone/2363996#2363996)

In that answer I show how to recursively construct and deconstruct a NSManagedObject graph to and from a JSON structure.  It is quite a bit easier than the path you are going down right now.

Comment: Marcus, I do have the many-many relationships set up already. I have a whole bunch of objects that I'm updating via JSON. I'm updating each object with the -setValuesForKeysWithDictionary method. The JSON includes the relationships for categories, so I was hoping to do all the updates in one round. By capturing the input with -setValue, I was planning on converting the array of category titles to the proper objects and assign the relationships.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a 1:1 relationship defined, so you are trying to say that the article belongs to one and only one category.

When you populate one object you may need to create the other; so when an article is created you will need to check your core data store for an object of the correct type and if it does not exist you create it. When you have the object, either pre-existing or just created, you either assign (relationship of one) it to the relationship ivar Category* or (relationship of many) add it to the NSSet* expressing the relationship.

So yes you do need to lookup and assign an actual object, since you must create a relationship to an object in the managed object context, and if it doesn't exist it must be created before that relationship can be made.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it is in fact a many-many relationship. I'll make that clearer in the question. I understand I'll need to do a lookup, but my question is how best to do that, via a fetch in the method or checking an array of all possible categories?

Comment: I would do a fetch - it's not heavyweight and it would be too easy to get your array out of sync with the actual store. Creating a "CategoryCatalog" object in the store that you add every category to as you create them would do pretty much the same as a fetch anyway as it will generate faults and do fetches automatically when you check the Categories property for existence of the category for the current article.