# Core Data with json

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data

This question is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone). I am using the JSON Library found at http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/.

My Core Data object model has a many-to-many relationship to itself and as such, has a set for its sub object. In JSON, the set is represented through an array of object ids. Nothing really exotic.

When I am calling `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` on the managed object with the object structure I get from parsing the json string, I receive this exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayM minusSet:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6c7b440'

If someone can explain why, I'm all ears. I also receive some exception from undefined key but this is understandable(JSON contains extra fields) and totally manageable.

Now my question is:

Am I missing something here because in the other question, the person who answered and OP didn't report any of this problem. I could patch it and handle the faulty operation by overriding `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` and passing when the key is a relationship but this makes the code a lot less generic which I quite like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that your JSON deserialization is creating arrays, but managed object to-many relationships are represented by sets.  I.e. you need NSSet rather than NSArray.  You can convert an NSArray to an NSSet by doing `[NSSet setWithArray:theArray]`.