# What's the suggested way to exchange structure data among iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, core-data, synchronization

Take `Purchase Order` as an example. There is `Purchase Order header` and one or more rows of `Purchase Order details`:

```
            +--- PO detail 1
            |
PO header --+--- PO detail 2
            | 
           ...
            | 
            +--- PO detail n
```

Assuem the POs are stored in a Core Data database. What's the suggested way to exchange *some* PO records among iOS devices, using the same app? I am thinking of packing the records in json format, zip and email to recipient(s). Is there any built-in mechanism in Core Data to serialize data in one device and de-serialize in another device? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in API for translating the data.  I recommend and use JSON as a transport format.  I wrote a generic (and rough) recursive parser in answer to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone/2363996#2363996).