# nsjsonserialization in ios5?

Tags: json, ios5

I have been reading that there is a now library in ios 5 that allows you to serialize & deserialize JSON data.  I can't for the life of me find examples or the framework in my /Developer folder.  Anyone have luck locating/working with this?  If so could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is now public in iOS 5, and there's an example of its use in the [Tweeting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011191) sample app.

Comment: There was no mention of NSJSONSerialization in that Tweeting sample. Maybe it changed?

Comment: Mike - It's used in the TweetingViewController's getPublicTimeline: method.

Comment: And so it is! There is some odd bug with safari. Try going to TweetingViewController.m and CMD+F and type "JSONSerial" and nothing comes up even though its clearly there. I have Safari 5.1.6.

Comment: @MikeS Safari probably only matches words that match from the beginning?

Answer (score 16):

I'm using it and it's quite simple, just import the library:

```
#import <Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.h>
```

and begin to use it.

Here there's a small but good tutorial: http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-11/inside-ios-

Answer (score 5):

It is actually part of the Foundation framework, been trying to use it since last night and for the purpose of actually serializing a dictionary to a JSON representation it works quite fine. Sadly I've not tested it the other way around.
Trust me the doc is there and it is no private API, sadly as you observed there are no examples.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across iOS5 JSON support in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5), which is part of an [excellent series of iOS5 tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

Answer (score 2):

Now iOS5 itself has the ability to serialize and de-serialize the json objects,
 it will manage all the process behind the scene, and you will be getting easily 
 customizable foundation objects (NSArray,NSDictionary,NSString...) 
 Based on your flavor you represented. 
    As brainjam suggest [This is the good tutorial to begin with](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5). Hope your fingers can play around with json objects easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using following simple code you can convert web data into JSON .

In this code "`webData`" is the data you get when you hit web service.

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```