# Core Data and JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i am using SBJSON and Core Data for the first time. I have a an Entity like this :

```
myEntity {
NSString *contenu;
NSString *first;
NSString *previous;
}
```

I would like to create my `JSON` with this entity, and second question, i would like to store a `JSON` in my Entity Core Data ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "store a `JSON` in my Entity Core Data`.

To convert an Entity into a JSON structure for sending out you can turn the entity into a `NSDictionary`.  From there you can use `SBJSON` to turn that `NSDictionary` into a `JSON` string.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone/2363996#2363996) I detailed how to do this.  It is sample code but it explains how to get everything working.