# Create json string from core data and vice versa?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsjsonserialization

I have got entities in core data with one to many relationship. How can I convert data in my entities to json string and populate core data entities with json string once it is created?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

for core data to json:

fetch the data from your coredata according to your requirements, & then converts it into json.

visit this link to c[ore data to json](http://touchalicious.com/blog/2009/10/25/turn-core-data-models-into-json.html)
also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone)

for json to core data

1)convert JSON to native Cocoa data types (NSDictionary and NSArray)
2)convert NS* into Core Data object

that means you can retrieve your json data into any array or any object & then insert that object or data into core data.

get data from json like this

```
NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray* )[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    Book.name = [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        Book.ID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
```

now insert this Book data into core data

Comment: Any guidance or tutorial how can I accomplish this conversion?

Comment: How can I convert my data into json first?